# How to formate date and set datepicker using jquery

Tags: jquery, datepicker

My date time is "10-jun-2014 3:50:57 PM" but i want to be "10/06/2014" and set in date picker.

Code:

```
var dateValue="10-jun-2014 3:50:57 PM";
var finalValue=new Date(dateValue);
$("#txtdatepicker").datepicker({
dateformat:'dd/mm/yy'
}).datepicker("setDate",finalValue);
```

but shows date format is undefined.

Comment: `dateformate` with e?

Comment: The problem is with `new Date(dateValue);`, it is not converting it to date.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but this should work:

```
var dateValue = "10-jun-2014 3:50:57 PM";
var finalValue = new Date(dateValue);
$("#txtdatepicker").datepicker({
    format: 'dd/mm/yy'
}).datepicker("setDate", finalValue);
```

I think it needs to just be `format` instead of `dateformate` [here's a link to the docs regarding format](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/options.html#format)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change `dateformat` to `dateFormat` (notice the capital `F`), like so:

```
var dateValue="10-jun-2014 3:50:57 PM";
var finalValue=new Date(dateValue);
$("#txtdatepicker").datepicker({
dateFormat:'dd/mm/yy'
}).datepicker("setDate",finalValue);
```